# Do casinos really use expected value calculations?

Tags: probability

I wonder if casinos really care about the expected value of certain games.

Suppose my game has a negative expected value (so the casino wins) of \$5.

Now we have one player playing the game. Would this not mean, that no matter how often the player plays, we could get a maximum of \$5 out of him.

But \$5 per player does not sound a lot to me. To me this would imply, if I had only 10 players visiting my casino I could only profit $50 and that only if they play for a long time.

Would it not be more reasonable to have something of an "adjustable" expected value that goes to minus infinity, so that if one person plays the game often we could expect a bigger profit than if he plays it only a couple of times?

Comment: Isn't the expected value of a game calculated with respect to playing the game *once*? I mean, the casino expects to win every time you play one of their games, right?

Comment: To me the expected value is the avarage of playing the game an infinite amount of time.

Comment: If the expected value (from a probabilistic view point the outcome if the game is  played once) goes to minus infinity, then all players would lose and then the casino would go out of business. It is true though that slot machines do not operate with the expected value. For each player, the expected outcome is always tilted in favor of the casino, that's how they stay in business. So there is nothing fair in the gambling industry.

Comment: No, it does not mean you can get a maximum of $5 out of him. It means that you will get, *on average*, $5 out of him *per game*. In particular, you can get much more (or less). It doesn't make sense to calculate "expected vaue for playing a game infinitely many times", as that would always be zero, plus or minus infinity (assuming the rules remain constant). Anyway, this question is not really about mathematics (although you seem to be genuinely confused about the meaning of the expected value, which *would* be a question about mathematics if worded properly).

Comment: So in you example the value of win $per$ $game$ converges to exactly $5 for infinitely many games. Nevertheless its the win per game.

Comment: Maybe the confusion stems from the fact that the law of large numbers that you're referring to applies to the *average* loss per game, not the total loss. For the total loss, multiply it by $n$; if $n$ is very large then $-5n $ is very negative

Comment: I won $5 at a casino once.

Comment: @tomasz Assuming the rules remain constant and are memoryless ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By the definition you have ascribed to the phrase "expected value", I doubt that the casinos give it consideration.

However, usual meaning of the term "expected value" is very different from how you are using it. The usual meaning of "expected value" is *already* what you call "adjustible" — the expected value of playing $N$ times is $N$ times the expected value of playing once.<sup>*</sup>

(to be clear, I mean that if you go to the roulette wheel, stay for 27 spins, then leave, you have played the game 27 times, not once)

*: I assume for simplicity here that you play the same way each time. If you vary your betting, you need to make the appropriate weighted sum, but works out to the houses expected take to be a fixed percentage of the total amount you bet over all plays. Similar adjustments need to be made if you place bets with different odds — e.g. in roulette the house expects a greater percentage of your money placed on five number bets than it does on other bets.

Comment: I see. Is this the result of the linearity of the expected value?

Comment: @Theodor: Right.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no.

Any such system would make the game heavily in the favor of the casino when a player plays first time. But then, why would any new player play the game? If a Casino cannot attract new players, they would become broke after a while...

Comment: [citation needed]

Comment: "why would any new player play the game? " people _do_ play games that are weighted against them...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich With expected value minus infinity?

Comment: ...which [expected value minus infinity] contradicts his next sentence "if one person plays the game often we could expect a bigger profit than if he plays it only a couple of times".

Comment: @Winther Not really. You could design the game this way: First time you play, you lose your money, no matter the outcome. Second time you play the game regularly, but you only win 50% of the usual prize. Third time, you win 75%, and so on......This approach would fit the post... But my question stays: why would anyone play the game the first time?

Comment: Fair enough. You are answering the last question of OP at face value and in that regards you're right - a game where EV $\to -\infty$ would be a terrible game. My point was simply that the last question does not really make sense in light of the preceding comments about how OP thinks EV works.

Comment: In the sense in which the OP seems to be using the term, yes.

Answer (score 0):

In the casino example, the expected value is what your average gain/loss will be when you play the game "for a very long time" (let the number of plays $\rightarrow \infty$). You can think of this like a horizontal asymptote. Functions can cross horizontal asymptotes infinitely many times (just look at the function $\sin(x) / x$), but as you let $ x \rightarrow \infty$ the function gets closer to the asymptote. Assuming certain betting strategies your gains and losses will fluctuate greatly from each individual game, but if you play the game enough times you'll get closer to the expected value. In practice, if someone is on a cold streak and is losing money they will be discouraged to continue playing so their number of plays will terminate before approaching the expected value.

As mentioned in the comments, however, you need a nice balance because if the expected value is too large in the casino's favor, people will always lose and no one will go to your casino causing you to go out of business.

So I don't know for sure, but I'd say it's possible that for certain games some sort of expected value is utilized.

Answer (score 0):

The expectations are tuned in such a way that they are minimally positive for the casino, because otherwise another bank, or casino, disguised as a player would be able win again the first in the long run. Nevertheless the rules are looking pretty fair and "interesting" to the prospective player.

This minimal edge for the casino is guaranteed, e.g.,  by the two zeros. For  the average player they don't have a big influence, since usually he is broke due to limited resources before their effect plays a rôle.

The decisive reason why the casinos have the upper hand is the fact that usually players don't stop before they have lost all their money.